# Can I change whole image base of binary? (gcc)

Tags: compilation, binary, elf

I want to make image base of binary to `0x09000000`.
However, by default, the image base is `0x08000000`.

I know the option like
gcc **-Wl,--section-start=.text=0x09000000** ...

But the result of above command is like below.
(Some sections are still mapped at `0x080*****` address.)

```
Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type            Addr     Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
  [ 0]                   NULL            00000000 000000 000000 00      0   0  0
  [ 1] .text             PROGBITS        09000000 001000 002f92 00  AX  0   0 16
  [ 2] .interp           PROGBITS        08048154 000154 000013 00   A  0   0  1
  [ 3] .note.ABI-tag     NOTE            08048168 000168 000020 00   A  0   0  4
  [ 4] .hash             HASH            08048188 000188 00002c 04   A  5   0  4
  [ 5] .dynsym           DYNSYM          080481b4 0001b4 000060 10   A  6   1  4
  [ 6] .dynstr           STRTAB          08048214 000214 000056 00   A  0   0  1
  [ 7] .gnu.version      VERSYM          0804826a 00026a 00000c 02   A  5   0  2
  [ 8] .gnu.version_r    VERNEED         08048278 000278 000020 00   A  6   1  4
  [ 9] .rel.dyn          REL             08048298 000298 000008 08   A  5   0  4
  [10] .rel.plt          REL             080482a0 0002a0 000018 08  AI  5  23  4
  [11] .init             PROGBITS        080482b8 0002b8 000023 00  AX  0   0  4
  [12] .plt              PROGBITS        080482e0 0002e0 000040 04  AX  0   0 16
  [13] .plt.got          PROGBITS        08048320 000320 000008 00  AX  0   0  8
  [14] .fini             PROGBITS        09002f94 003f94 000014 00  AX  0   0  4
  [15] .rodata           PROGBITS        09002fb0 003fb0 000023 00   A  0   0 16
  [16] .eh_frame_hdr     PROGBITS        09002fd4 003fd4 000024 00   A  0   0  4
  [17] .eh_frame         PROGBITS        09002ff8 003ff8 0000a0 00   A  0   0  4
  [18] .init_array       INIT_ARRAY      09004098 004098 000010 00  WA  0   0  4
  [19] .fini_array       FINI_ARRAY      090040a8 0040a8 000008 00  WA  0   0  4
  [20] .jcr              PROGBITS        090040b0 0040b0 000004 00  WA  0   0  4
  [21] .dynamic          DYNAMIC         090040b4 0040b4 0000e8 08  WA  6   0  4
  [22] .got              PROGBITS        0900419c 00419c 000004 04  WA  0   0  4
  [23] .got.plt          PROGBITS        090041a0 0041a0 000018 04  WA  0   0  4
  [24] .data             PROGBITS        090041c0 0041c0 000084 00  WA  0   0 32
  [25] .bss              NOBITS          09004250 004244 0000d8 00  WA  0   0 16
```

***Question1.***

I want to move the image base of binary to `0x09000000`,
...I mean, I want to move whole sections to `original starting address + 0x01000000`
But above option can only change the `.text` section.

Is there any compile option that I can use?

***Question2.***

Actually, as you can see the above result,
"**-Wl,--section-start=.text=0x09000000**" option not only changes *.text* section,
but also changes some data-relative sections such as *.init_array*, *.got*, ...

Why is the compiler doing this weird thing?

Comment: *Why* do you want this? What is the *real* problem you want to solve by changing the base for all the segments? And are you sure it's going to work, and the operating system and its loader will allow it?

Comment: The overall layout (segements and their addreses) of the final image is mainly determined by a linker script. It you want a different base address, the usual approach is to use a modifed linker script.

Comment: By the way, you know how to change the `.text` segment with the `--section-start` option. It shouldn't be to hard to extrapolate that knowledge into how to do it for the other segments.